# Authentication failed while git clone

Tags: ssh, authentication, gcp

I created a VM and installed docker and git and then tried to clone a github project.

git clone "project_url"

Gave correct username and pwd but after that I am getting below error
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
fatal: Authentication failed for ...

Am I missing something

Comment: I think this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775869/message-support-for-password-authentication-was-removed-please-use-a-personal) will help you

Answer (score 0):

You need to either upload your SSH public key to your account, and then use SSH for your connection to GitHub; or, create a personal access token which you will use in place of your password.

To create a PAT, go to Settings > Developer Settings > Personal access tokens, and create one with the permissions you need. Copy the token somewhere safe, and enter it instead of your password when you are prompted by the command line.